# How to extract the values after Comparison Operators in string using regex and find if value is object/ str or int/float in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have doubt, SO I have a string ( `str ="cars>=30 and jeeps=='one'"`)Now I want to extract the values after Comparison Operators(In my case the values after >= and == )using re and find whether the value is d-type int or object/string.Is there any way to find this out?

My code:

```
x = "cars>=20 and jeeps =='one'"
if 'and' in x:
    r=x.split('and')
    l=[]
    for i in r:
        print(i)
        l.append(re.findall(r'([<>]=?|==)(\d+)', i))
        print(l)
elif 'or' in x:
    print(x)

this gives
cars>=20 
[[('>=', '20')]]
jeeps =='one'
[[('>=', '20')], []]
```

Excepted output:

```
['20','one']
```

Comment: When I run this, it produces 4 lines of output.

Comment: ya, cars>=20 
[[('>=', '20')]]
 jeeps =='one'
[[('>=', '20')], []] this i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>=]+\s*'?(?P<value>\w+)'?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rTs1iT/1).

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>=]+\s*'?(?P<value>\w+)'?""")
x = "cars>=20 and jeeps =='one'"

result = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(x)}
print(result)
```

Which would yield

```
{'cars': '20', 'jeeps': 'one'}
```

See [**another demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/GtxB2L).

Comment: But when a float value is given like "20.09". Why is it giving only 20 as the value?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use re, but (almost) produces the desired output (quotes are left around `one`):

```
x = "cars>=20 and jeeps =='one'"
if 'and' in x:
    r=x.split('and')
    l=[]
    for i in r:
        for op in ('>=','=='):
            r2 = i.split(op)
            if len(r2) > 1:
                l.append(r2[-1])
                break
    print(l)
elif 'or' in x:
    print(x)
```